re.findall() in python for escape sequences
I was trying to find out all escape sequences in a file but failed. This is a minimal reproducible example:
Code:
import re
matches = re.findall(r'"(\\\d+)+"', r'"\123\124\125"')
print(matches)

Expected result:
['"\123\124\125"']

Observed result:
['\\125']

Why?

Use a non-capture group: r'"(?:\\\d+)+"'

When there are capture groups, re.findall() just returns the matches for the capture group . Change it to a non-capturing group.

@Barmar and anubhava, thanks!
